# AngularJS http service doesn't read JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I have this gallery which AngularJS expressions for  "src" and "alt".
The data for the expressions is in a JSON-file.

Without the JSON-file, i.e. with all the data for the expressions in the AngularJS controller file, it works. But I need the data to be in the JSON file and the way I tried to connect with $html doesn't seem to work, I see no images at all.

What am I missing? Thanks a lot for your help!

```js
var galleryApp = angular.module('galleryApp', []);

galleryApp.controller('galleryController', function galleryController($scope, $http) {
$http.get('images.json').success(function(data) {
 $scope.images = data;
 });
});

/*
and this is the JSON in a file called images.json
[

{
 'source'  : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg',
 'altText' : 'Jeremiah Wilson'
},
{
 'source'  : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg',
 'altText' : 'Jeremiah Wilson'
},
{
 'source'  : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg',
 'altText' : 'Jeremiah Wilson'
},
{
 'source'  : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg',
 'altText' : 'Jeremiah Wilson'
},
{
 'source'  : 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg',
 'altText' : 'Jeremiah Wilson'
}
]

*/
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}
li {
 list-style: none;
}
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
#mainGallery { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
#mainGallery div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}
#mainGallery div img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #mainGallery div { margin: 0; }
  #mainGallery { padding: 0; }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-controller = "galleryController" id="mainGallery">
 
     <div ng-repeat="item in images">
         <img src="{{item.source}}" alt="{{item.altText}}">
        </div>
    
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Right above your $scope assignment statement, try setting a breakpoint in the console and see what is returned by `data` in that function. There is a chance you are correctly getting the data but just not loading it into the object or using it correctly.

Comment: Your JSON file doesn't contain valid JSON. Fix it. JSON keys and values must be surrounded by double quotes, not single quotes. You should have an error in your browser console. Leave it opened, always, while developing.

Comment: I'm too tired I suppose, very embarrassing, of course, the double quotes, thanks so much! @JB Nizet do you want to copy/paste your comment as an answer so i can tick it as the solution? thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format that you are using is not valid. Paste the following formatted code in your JSON file

```
[
{
    "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg",
    "altText": "Jeremiah Wilson"
},
{
    "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg",
    "altText": "Jeremiah Wilson"
},
{
    "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg",
    "altText": "Jeremiah Wilson"
},
{
    "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg",
    "altText": "Jeremiah Wilson"
},
{
    "source": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg",
    "altText": "Jeremiah Wilson"
}]
```

You can always validate your JSON at [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/)